# How to display WordPress Categories on front page

Tags: wordpress, categories, posts

Given are 5 categories & their sub-categories in my WordPress Website. Sub-categories contains posts. I want to display categories (Only categories) on my front page. When a user click on any category, I want to show it's all sub-categories on another page and when user click on any sub-category, I want to display all the posts that category contains.

Please tell me how to do it? I have studied WordPress category guides but did not get any clue.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following code to your front page template:

wp_list_categories();

That will print out a list of all your categories. You can then hide the subcategories if you wish using CSS.

By default, clicking a category link will then open the category page, which uses the category.php template, and this will show all the posts in that category.

More information here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories

To list the subcategories of a particular category:

```
$category_id = get_cat_ID('Category Name');
$categories = get_categories(array('child_of' => $category_id));
foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' .       $category->name.'</a><br> ';
}
```

Comment: Alright I got it working now. What about displaying only subcategories on the next page?

Comment: Do you mean showing only sub categories of the category shown on the category page?

Comment: @Danishiqbal I've edited my answer above to show how to list the subcategories of a particular category.

Comment: Thanks Seano,
Please see this page:
http://sodagir.com/blog/
I have my 2 categories here now. These categories contains sub categories. What i want to do is when i click on 'Laptop / Computer' it will show 'laptop / computers' sub-categories on the next page.

Comment: This is what i did with your code, i added category name on the first line and copied it in between <?php?> tags.
nothing is showing up.

Comment: @Danishiqbal have you put that code in the category.php template?

Comment: oh !! i have no idea about category.php
so, let me study it first then i'll get back to you again.

Comment: By the way i am using Archive.php instead of category.php. Does this makes any difference?
And yes I tried by copying your given code to home.php, single.php and Archive.php. nothing is showing up.

Comment: category.php is the template that is used when you visit a category page, like Laptops & Computers, so you must put that code in there. If you feel that I have answered your question, please mark it as accepted. Thanks